# In Google sign how to change the uri?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-console-developer

How to change the url using google developer console shown in the screen below?

[image]

I have a requirement where I need to change the url under the heading "Signing in will redirect you to". I am unable to find any option on google consent screen. Any help would be highly appreciated.